# Python Debugger: Wrong content of registers associated with threads

Tags: python, debugging, ctypes

I'm studying how to build a debugger in **python**, with the guidance of "**Gray Hat Python**" debugger code, I executed a code that takes an input the **PID** and then prints the values of the registers for the threads associated with the given process.
The problem is: whatever process I provide it keeps printing "**0x00000000**" for every thread associated with the process, which I believe isn't correct.

Here are the written codes (directly from the book):

[my_debugger_defines.py)](http://codepad.org/viFJMH2C) : this file contains the mapping of Structures and Unions for windows API (I don't think the problem is here)

[my_debugger.py](http://codepad.org/3s0EKeD9) : The debugger code itself

and the debugger tester [my_test.py](http://codepad.org/4xQ3kQXs)

I can't think of a problem that might cause this, except that there is a mistake in identifying the threads associated with the process.

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe reading a foreign process' registers only works when the process is suspended rather than running?